# force ssh to change dir after login based on config

Tags: ssh, ssh-config

Is there any way to force `ssh` to change it's working dir in `~/.ssh/config` or by using other configuration files?

I have a lot of servers with different environments. Each environment is installed in a specific directory and it would be really helpful to be in this specific directory right after login.

Unfortunately, sometimes several environments can be hosted on the same server.

That's why I need to make it config based, as currently I have a separate entry in config for each env. Example:

```
Host env1
User me
Port 2222
# here directory should be /srv/project/env1
HostName 172.16.16.2

Host env2_test
User me
Port 2222
# here directory should be /srv/project/env2_test
HostName 172.16.16.2

Host env54
User me
Port 2225
# here directory should be /srv/project/env54
HostName 172.16.16.3
```

I can do it with `ssh -t env54 'cd /srv/project/env54 ; bash'`, but it's annoying to retype it each time or even put it in an `alias`.

I believe the *nix way is to handle it via configuration.

Comment: I've never seen a way to do this with pure SSH config files. http://superuser.com/questions/372217/ssh-config-setting-initial-directory-after-login. You'll have to devise either something local to each system, or use an extra command that you append onto your SSH prior to running them to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the server, in `.profile` or whatever is run when you log in:

```
if [ -n "$USE_DIR_A" ]; then
    cd dir_a
elif [ -n "$USE_DIR_B" ]; then
    cd dir_b
fi
```

Then, on the local machine, set **both** variables:

```
export USE_DIR_A=yes
export USE_DIR_B=yes
```

and, set your `.ssh/config` like this:

```
Host env1
User me
Port 2222
# here directory should be /srv/project/env1
SendEnv USE_DIR_A
HostName 172.16.16.2

Host env2_test
User me
Port 2222
# here directory should be /srv/project/env2_test
SendEnv USE_DIR_B
HostName 172.16.16.2
```

Of course, you could just have one ssh config that sends one variable, and set that variable to the directory you want for each machine, but that's not what you asked for.

Beware SSH connection sharing though: it can affect which scripts are run on start-up in subsequent connections.

Comment: Servers are often configured to reject most environment variables. You may need to add an `AcceptEnv` directive in `sshd_config`. Locale variables are often accepted, so if `USE_DIR_A` doesn't get through and you can't change the server configuration, try calling it `LC_USE_DIR_A`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `command=cd /srv/project/env1 && bash` flag in remote server `~/.ssh/authorized_key` file for appropriate public key for source server. For more information you can check this [question](https://serverfault.com/questions/56086/ssh-how-to-include-t-command-in-the-ssh-config-file) on serverfault and for more information about useful options like command in public key in authorized_keys file check this [blog](http://larstobi.blogspot.in/2011/01/restrict-ssh-access-to-one-command-but.html).

I tried this on my test machine (Centos 6.5 on Virtualbox) and it works fine.

```
[root@CentOS-VM1 ~]# ssh nischay@localhost
[nischay@CentOS-VM1 demo]$ pwd
/tmp/demo
```

Content of `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` is

```
command="cd /tmp/demo && bash" ssh-dss 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 root@CentOS-VM1
```

Other options like port number, alias for hostname, username, private key and port forwarding options you can mention in `~/.ssh/config` file in source box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that I've understood your question correctly and that you have different SSH ports for different environments.  If so:-

Add a variation of the following to your `.bash_profile` on each remote machine:-

```
if [[ ! -z $SSH_CLIENT ]]; then
    PORT=$(echo "$SSH_CLIENT" | awk '{print $3}')
    case $PORT in
        2222)
            cd /srv/project/env1
        ;;
        2225)
            cd /srv/project/env2
        ;;
    esac
if
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately ports usually are the same for different projects on one machine. Ports may differ only between machines.